# In my save load system where should I save the camera/s positions and rotations in the code I have?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have now one camera of the player and I want to save it with the player. Later I might have other cameras but since this camera is following the player I want to save it with the player when saving the player position and rotation.

Should I add a new class for the camera data or all I need is just to add the Player script also to the camera I want to save it's data ? The script now is attached to the Player only.

The player data :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{
    public float[] position;
    public float[] rotation;
    
    public PlayerData(Player player)
    {
        position = new float[3];
        position[0] = player.transform.position.x;
        position[1] = player.transform.position.y;
        position[2] = player.transform.position.z;

        rotation = new float[4];
        rotation[0] = player.transform.rotation.x;
        rotation[1] = player.transform.rotation.y;
        rotation[2] = player.transform.rotation.z;
        rotation[3] = player.transform.rotation.w;
    }
}
```

The player :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void SavePlayer()
    {
        SaveSystem.SavePlayer(this);
    }

    public void LoadPlayer()
    {
        PlayerData data = SaveSystem.LoadPlayer();

        Vector3 position;
        position.x = data.position[0];
        position.y = data.position[1];
        position.z = data.position[2];
        transform.position = position;

        Quaternion rotation;
        rotation.x = data.rotation[0];
        rotation.y = data.rotation[1];
        rotation.z = data.rotation[2];
        rotation.w = data.rotation[3];
        transform.rotation = rotation;
    }
}
```

The saving system :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public static class SaveSystem
{
    public static void SavePlayer(Player player)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.bin";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        PlayerData data = new PlayerData(player);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();
    }

    public static PlayerData LoadPlayer()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.bin";
        if(File.Exists(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

            PlayerData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
            stream.Close();

            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Save file not found in " + path);

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Using it in another script just to show how I'm saving :

```
player.GetComponent<Player>().SavePlayer();
```

and loading :

```
player.GetComponent<Player>().LoadPlayer();
```

I want to implement somewhere in the code also the camera data position and rotation to be saved and loaded. The camera is not child of the player.

Comment: In general I wouldn't use the `BinaryFormatter`, yes it is easy to implement but stores so much overhead. You could rather implement your own `ToBytes` and `FromBytes` methods. Of course the data stored here is not very big anyway so this is just a general hint ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since your PlayerData class is not player specific at all I see no problem in adding a little modification to allow storing the camera data in the same way.
Just rename it to TransformData and you're done.

The saving system I would alter to:

```
public static class SaveSystem
{
    public const string PLAYER_STORAGE = "player";
    public const string CAMERA_STORAGE = "camera";

    // replaces the SavePlayer method
    public static void SaveData(string storage, Transform transform)
    {
        [...]
        string path = AssembleStoragePath(storage);
        [...]
        TransformData data = new TransformPlayerData(transform);
        [...]
    }

    public static bool TryLoadData(string storage, out Vector3 position, out Quaternion rotation)
    {
        TransformData data = LoadData(storage);
        if(data == null)
        {
            position = Vector3.zero;
            rotation = Quaternion.Identity;
            return false;
        }

        position = new Vector3(
            data.position[0],
            data.position[1],
            data.position[2]);

        rotation = new Quaternion(
            data.rotation[0],
            data.rotation[1],
            data.rotation[2],
            data.rotation[3]);

        return true;
    }

    // replaces LoadPlayer method
    private static TransformData LoadData(string storage)
    {
        string path = AssembleStoragePath(storage);
        [...]   
    }

    private static string AssembleStoragePath(string storage)
    {
        return $"{Application.persistentDataPath}/{storage}.bin";
    }
}
```

The new constant strings are for not having hard coded strings in your storage calls.
Player data for example would be stored via `SaveSystem.SaveData(SaveSystem.PLAYER_STORAGE, player.transform);`

This way your storage system can be reused for any transform and your outside code (the stored objects) do not have to know about the the stored format (TransformData).
This allows you to exchange the storage logic in the future without having to modify your stored classes (currently your player depends on PlayerData, which is bad).